# make a custom url for create action with RESTful routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4 I'm trying to make a custom root for a particular action in the users controller, so i want my restful resources for users still like they are, but change only the url for the `create` action and make it to be for example `/account/register`. I'm trying do this as the follow but it seem not work :

```
resources :users, except: [:create] # first i eliminate creation of create root
resources :users, path: "account/register", as: :users, only: [:create] # then i just try to make a custom route for only create action
```

i want still using users_path and not change any of my routing helper in the view, please any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
post "/account/register" => "users#create", as: :users
```

This will create a route where `/account/register` points to UsersController#create. This can be referenced with `users_path`.

Comment: this gives error, are you sure for the syntax ? i want the url /users to be /account/register

Comment: What error do you get? I updated the code to point to /account/register.

Comment: i can't run the server, i also update your code to be post :user => but not work too

Comment: I misunderstood you the first time. The above statement should now be valid and do exactly what you want.

Comment: Well, it will be hard to help you out, without more context. The code is perfectly valid.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35311/discussion-between-kevin-sjoberg-and-medbo)

Comment: ok i'm in chat, and it works now but for GET it give the /account/create rather than /users

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
match '/account/register' => 'user#create', via: :post
```

Comment: This will not create a named route and it's more convenient to use the VERB methods.

Comment: it's not Restful ! i have a view to create users that have form_for(@user) , this means it post to /users path, but your solution don't change /users to /account/register